# How to get daemon access token for self account

Tags: authentication, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am trying to create a web app whose main task is fixing appointment.

I do not want to access any mail data of the logged in user.

I only want to implicitly login using an outlook account (my account) to which I have admin access. I want to connect with this account, fetch its calendar events and display the events to the logged in user so that the user can select any available spots.

I have registered my app in the azure portal and provided all the application permissions (earlier I tried with Delegated permissions as well; but I guess delegated permissions are not for my use case).

Thereafter, I tried to fetch the token for my profile using:

```
this.http.post(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
      {
        client_id: 'my-client-uuid',
        scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_secret: '****myclientsecret****'
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Host: 'login.microsoftonline.com',
          'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }
      ).subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
      });
```

as suggested in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#token-request) article.

However, my request fails while doing this and states that the request body must contain 'grant_type' when I am clearly sending that.

Can someone please suggest me how I can implicitly get data from my own outlook account in a web app.

Update: I used the suggestion from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266377/post-request-to-graph-api-fails-with-bad-request), appears that the request is going through now. However, the browser throws CORS error saying that the server didn't have appropriate headers.

Update 2: Found this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#setup-required-for-single-page-apps), which seems to address the exact issue I am facing. I however already have the redirect URI for SPA. The issue still persists.

Comment: Is the application solely a SPA or does it have a backend component?

Comment: Its does have a backend compnent.

Comment: Your making this request from the backend component? I'm assuming you are running on Node?